# What direction does Chevy impala power steering flow?

Tags: power-steering

[image]

I have a 2008 Chevy impala and I am having trouble understanding how the power steering runs and how the fluid is circled through the pump and back to the rack. I understand there must be a return line and a high pressure line for it to be easy to steer. I have provided a diagram above ,I don’t understand the concept , due to the fact that there is many different lines coming from the rack . I see 4 lines and I thought there was only 2, the two extra lines being the smaller ones.pleas e try to use the diagram listings(the numbers) in the explanation.The lines at the very bottom by the belt accessories loop together (to avoid confusion).

What I think happens: 
 The fluid begins at the pump , goes through the high pressure hose and down to the rack to make it easy to steer.

Confusion: 
1.how do the fluid get back to the pump?

2.What are the two small lines on the rack in the diagram
3.Why do the lines at the bottom by the accessories loop and don’t go straight back to the pump?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The pump supplies the HP fluid, which goes via 3 which is a cooling loop

The control block will only use the amount of fluid according to the steering input so there is an excess return line back to the reservoir - separate to or combined with the pump depending on the system.

Comment: Can you go more in depth about the flow of the whole system ?

Comment: Not the math just the direction and the flow of passage , and the cycle of the fluid , like goes through 3 to the rack and then where to after

Comment: One of the small tubes (shown but not numbered) on the rack is the balance tube for the tierod bellows. As one side collapses the air is pushed into the expanding opposite side. The process reverses when the bellows expands back to the neutral position.